# AXIS2 generating wrong SOAP Message because of encoding. how to fix it?

Tags: xml, web-services, wsdl, apache-axis, wsdl2java

**QUESTION**: how can I use a different *encoding (charset and transfer)* with axis?

Here is my client:

```
public Object[] invoke(String xmlRepresentation)
            throws CustomApplicationException {

            Object[] responseWS = null;
            RPCServiceClient serviceClient = new RPCServiceClient();            
            Options options = serviceClient.getOptions();           
            options.setAction("WBSREFT");
            options.setTo(new EndpointReference("http://localhost:6132"));
            QName qName = new QName(XML_SCHEMA, operation);

            Object[] args = new Object[] { "blablabla" };
            responseWS = serviceClient.invokeBlocking(qName, args, returnTypes);


            String responseAsString = (String) responseWS[0];
            return responseWS;

    }
```

Here is the SOAPEnvelope being generated (captured using TCP/IP Monitor):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
<WBSREFT xmlns="http://tempuri.org/LICPOCSampleService">
<arg0 xmlns="">blablabla</arg0>
</WBSREFT>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

WHY Axis2 generated this stupid encoding (http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope)???

Using Apache TCPMon I've captured this request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "WBSREFT"
User-Agent: Axis2
Host: 172.17.192.113:6133
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

102
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soapenv:Body>
         <WBSREFT xmlns="http://tempuri.org/LICPOCSampleService">
            <arg0 xmlns="">to cobol</arg0>
         </WBSREFT>
      </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>0
```

If I send the XML request using soapUI that's what TCPMon captures:

```
POST / HTTP/0.9
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ""
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1
Host: 172.17.192.113:6133
Content-Length: 265

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soapenv:Body>
         <WBSREFT xmlns="http://tempuri.org/LICPOCSampleService">
            <arg0 xmlns="">to cobol</arg0>
         </WBSREFT>
      </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I've noticed this weird output: 102 and 0 in the middle of the XML... what can it be?

Comment: I think you should also post the minimum code that reproducibly creates the broken SOAP request.

Comment: You post 3 XML fragments. Only the first one has the strange/broken encoding attribute. How did you produce the latter two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all Eclipse's plugin TCP/IP Monitor was apparently not giving me the right XML request leading me to wrong directions.

It was showing **encoding="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"**, while Apache TCPMon gave me different (RIGHT) results.

As [saua](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40342/saua) noted, problem was the Chunk encoding, which you can change with this (AND SOLVED MY PROBLEM):

```
options.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, Boolean.FALSE);
```

And to answer my question:

```
options.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.Constants.Configuration.CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: The chunk encoding is not a problem, it's a standardized way to transfer data. Why do you want to change it?

Comment: well, somehow the webservice wasn't understanding the encoding. it's a COBOL webservices.

Answer (score 2):

The 102 and 0 in the middle of the XML are artifacts of the "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" they are not part of the content you send.